# export xml data to html table

Tags: javascript, xml

I'm tring to export data from [this xml](http://www.meinrelaxsessel.com/gmerchantcenter.de.shop1.xml) to [this page](http://www.kuboweb.it/test/feed_xml-to-php5.php) without any results. The only information that I need to export in this page is the "g:sale_price"

I also export other datas in [this page](http://www.kuboweb.it/test/feed_xml-to-php3.php)

the code that i'm using is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<body onload="loadXMLDoc()">

<br><br>
<table id="demo"></table>

<script>

function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      myFunction(xmlhttp);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "./gmerchantcenter.de.shop1.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
function myFunction(xml) {
  var i;
  var xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Price</th></tr>";
  var x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("g:sale_price")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I can't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser console? And where do you call those functions (myFunction and loadXMLDoc)? It seems that you only defined them.

Comment: there are 2 errors `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` 
I'm not expert with js, I think I'm calling loadXMLDoc function onload and myFunction is called in the loadXMLDoc function